# Find the minimum value of $(1+\frac{1}{a_1})(2+\frac{1}{a_2})...(2020+\frac{1}{a_{2020}})$

Tags: optimization, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $(a_1,a_2,...a_{2020})$ be a permutation of $(1,2,...,2020)$. Find the minimum value of
> $$A =(1+\frac{1}{a_1})(2+\frac{1}{a_2})...(2020+\frac{1}{a_{2020}})$$

One can rewrite $A$ as
$$A = \frac {(a_1+1)(2a_2+1)...(2020a_{2020}+1)}{a_1a_2...a_{2020}}.$$

$(a_1,a_2,...a_{2020})$ be a permutation of $(1,2,...,2020)\Rightarrow a_1a_2...a_{2020} =2020! $

So we must find the minimum value of $(a_1+1)(2a_2+1)...(2020a_{2020}+1)$

I think equality happens when
$$a_1=2020;a_2=2019;...;a_{2020}=1,$$
but I have no idea on how to prove it.

Comment: Hint. Let's say $j < k$ are two indices, and you know that $a_j$ and $a_k$ take the values $u$ and $v$, with $u < v$, but you don't know which is which. How would you select $a_j$ and $a_k$ in order to minimize $A$?

Comment: @Anonymous   That's what I'm suspecting, too, but I still haven't been able to answer that question. You better say it ?

Comment: Well, what would be the expressions for $A$ in each of the two cases? Can you write them down?

Comment: @Anonymous   What are the 2 cases? I do not know what you mean

Comment: Where is the question from? A contest?

Comment: @CalvinKhor            Yes, it's the 1st mock test of my country's TST

Comment: The two cases are $a_j = u, a_k = v$ and $a_j = v, a_k = u$.

Comment: @Anonymous    As I said above, I have not answered that question, can you be more specific?

Comment: @Anonymous it is clear for which values of $a_is$, A will be minimum. The OP is asking what would be that minimum value.

Comment: Using AM-GM inequality, $ A\geq 2^{2020}$ But it doesn't necessarily mean than minimum value of $A=2^{2020}$ unless A actually takes that value.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha     Can you clarify the answer, please?

Comment: Please do not delete a question just after receiving an answer.  Doing so is rude to the person who took the time to answer your question, and is rude to potential future askers.

Comment: @abcccccc is a closed form solution expected?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I can see the rearrangement inequality.

\begin{align}
& \text{let } x_n = n. \Rightarrow x: \text{ Increasing Sequence.} \\
& \text{let } y_n = \dfrac {1} {n}. \Rightarrow y: \text{ Decreasing Sequence.} \\
\ \\
& \text{By rearranging $y_i$s, we get $\dfrac {1} {a_i}.$} \\
\ \\
\Rightarrow \; & (1+y_1)(2+y_2)\cdots(2020+y_{2020}) \geq A \geq (1+y_{2020})(2+y_{2019}) \cdots (2020+y_1) \\
& = \prod_{i=1}^{2020} \Big(i+\dfrac {1} {2000-i}\Big). \\
\ \\
\therefore \; & A \geq \prod_{i=1}^{2020} \Big( i + \dfrac {1} {2020-i} \Big) \\
& (a_{i} = 2021-i.)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$A = \frac{1}{2020!} \left(1+\frac{1}{1\cdot a_1}  \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{2\cdot a_2}  \right)\cdots\left(1+\frac{1}{2020\cdot a_{2020}}  \right)$$

**Lemma**: for $m<n$, if $(a_m,a_n)$ is a permutation of $(x,y)$ with $x<y$ then $$\left(1+\frac{1}{m\cdot a_m}  \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n\cdot a_n}  \right) \ge \left(1+\frac{1}{m\cdot y}  \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n\cdot x}  \right) \tag{1}$$

> **Proof**: for $m<n$ and $x<y$, proving $(1)$ is equivalent to prove
> $$\left(1+\frac{1}{m\cdot x}  \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n\cdot y}  \right) \ge \left(1+\frac{1}{m\cdot y}  \right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n\cdot x}  \right) \tag{2}$$
> and it is easy to have that $$(2)\iff(n-m)(y-x) \ge 0$$

For a set $(a_1,a_2,...,a_{2020})$ suppose there exists a couple $(a_m,a_n)$ such that $m<n$ and $a_m>a_n$, we can make $A$ smaller by switching the value of $a_m$ and $a_n$ by applying the lemma. In order words,
$$A(a_1,a_2,...,\color{red}{a_m},...,\color{red}{a_n},..,a_{2020}) \ge A(a_1,a_2,...,\color{red}{a_n},...,\color{red}{a_m},..,a_{2020})$$

Hence, $A$ reaches its minimum when $a_1>a_2>\cdots >a_{2020}$ or
$$A \ge \prod_{i=1}^{2020}\left(i+\frac{1}{(2021-i)}  \right)$$
with $a_i = 2021-i$ for $i=1,..., 2020$.

Q.E.D

Comment: Can you be more specific in that : apply the lemma for A ? More specific ?